# WinSCPSession error in parameter name 'HostName'. How it fix?

Tags: powershell, script, ftp, winscp

I created a script in WindowsPowerShell that sends files from the hard drive to an unsecured FTP server. However, I have an error problem that I don't know how to fix. I have Windows Powershell version 7.3.9 and the WinSCP module installed. I run the script as admin.

Below is the error information and my line of code:

```
New-WinSCPSession: D:\script\serverftp.ps1:15
Line |
   15 | $session = New-WinSCPSession -HostName $ftpServer -PortNumber $ftpPor …
      | ~~~~~~~~~
      | A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'HostName'.
```

```
# Create an FTP session without SSL/TLS encryption
$session = New-WinSCPSession -HostName $ftpServer -PortNumber $ftpPort -Credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($ftpUser, (ConvertTo-SecureString $ftpPassword -AsPlainText -Force))) -Protocol Ftp -FtpSecure None
```

Answer (score 1):

The parameters you are using should go to `New-WinSCPSessionOption`, not `New-WinSCPSession`.

Like this:

```
$sessionOption = New-WinSCPSessionOption -HostName $ftpServer -PortNumber $ftpPort -Credential (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($ftpUser, (ConvertTo-SecureString $ftpPassword -AsPlainText -Force))) -Protocol Ftp -FtpSecure None
$session = New-WinSCPSession -SessionOption $sessionOption
```

See also the official example:
https://github.com/tomohulk/WinSCP#example

Comment: Thanks Martin. It's working now!

By the way, Could you please let me know how to change this line to connect with FTPs as well?

Comment: I guess that `-FtpSecure Explicit`. Check the [documentation](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/WinSCP/5.7.3.2/Content/Functions%5CNew-WinSCPSessionOptions.ps1). If you need more details, please post new question.